# How to use a TypeScript function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I want to use the below given function called "translate" in a JavaScript file.
I have seen a answer on stackoverflow regarding this, but couldn't get what I had to do. Definitely the normal calling of function isn't working in this case

```
import queryString from "querystring";
import request from "request";
import { config } from "./config";

function translate(text: string, from: string, to: string) {
    const requestOptions = getRequestOptions();
    const params = {
        "from": from,
        "to": to,
        "text": text
    };

request.get(
    config.speech.translateApi.endPoind + "/Translate?" + queryString.stringify(params),
    requestOptions,
    (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(body);
    }
);
}
```

Comment: You'll have to compile the .ts file to a .js file, then include the .js file and call translate from it.

Comment: Won't the function give an error if it does not have proper values. As I want to give values to the function when I will it in JS file. So it won't work, i guess

Comment: Javascript has no concept of types, and Typescript type information does not exist at runtime. If you want type safety you will have to convert your project to use Typescript and rely on the compiler to enforce type safety for you.

Comment: I guess I have to find some other way to use the Microsoft translator API

Comment: BTW thanks for your answers and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a typescript project then you can do:

```
export const translate = () => {}

...

// anotherFile.js

import {translate} from './translate'
```

However even if you import it this way typescript will still need to compile your code before it can be used.

Comment: Thanks for answering mate!